# Error BOOTSTRAP SASS _is not a color for `darken'

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, scss

Este erro retorna quando eu ordeno em meu app.scss estes arquivos de @import, utilizando SASS/bootstrap@4.3.1 em um Mac. Preciso entender onde está o erro, se ao inverter a ordem (variaveis customizadas no final) o erro não acontece, e se há algum problema manter esta ultima ordem (sem erro):

> error sass/_variable.scss (Line 176: $color: "theme-color(#007bff)" is not a color for `darken')

```
// imports
@import "../sass/variable"; // Bootstrap variables
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";  // Bootstrap framework
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";  // Bootstrap Functions - custom
```

sem erro:

```
// imports
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";  // Bootstrap framework
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";  // Bootstrap Functions - custom
@import "../sass/variable"; // Bootstrap variables
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha é difícil explicar o porque do erro sem saber o que vc fez ai. Mas a documentação ajuda um pouco a esclarecer as coisas... Provavelmente vc mudou alguma **Chave Obrigatória**

> Por exemplo, nós usamos as chaves primary, success e danger do mapa $theme-colors, para links, botões e estados de formulários. Substituir os valores dessas chaves não deve apresentar problemas, mas removê-las pode causar problemas na compilação Sass.

Veja: https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#chaves-obrigat%C3%B3rias

---

Sobre inverter a ordem das suas variáveis o indicado realmente seria elas virem antes como diz a documentação, mas se vc mudou as variáveis direto no `variable.scss` o seu problema pode ser relacionado ao que disse anteriormente sobre as Chaves.

De qualquer forma, caso vc tenha mexido nesse arquivo veja que a própria documentação faz o `@import` das `variables` apos as `functions`

```
//Partes obrigatórias
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Partes opcionais
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
```

Veja: https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#importando

**Então mudar a ordem pode não apresentar efeitos indesejados.** *Apesar disso recomendo que faça uns testes com alguns componentes etc para confirmar que o CSS vai carregar como o esperado...*

---

**OBS:** Além disso, todas a variáveis do Bootstrap tem a flag `!default`, isso significa que vc pode sobrescrever o valor dessa variável de forma segura. Seu .scss ficaria parecido com isso: *(mas no seu caso pode não resolver se o valor que vc mudou foi diretamente na variável default do Bootstrap)*

```
// Suas sobrescrições de variáveis
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;

//Partes obrigatórias
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

Veja mais aqui: https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#vari%C3%A1veis-padr%C3%A3o

Comment: Primeiro obrigado pela resposta completa e detalhada! Agora eu não mudei nada, só criei um novo arquivo variable copiando o original variables, onde eu posso editar e desta forma não alterar o padrão. Após a instalação via npm do sass, bootstrap, jquery e popper tudo roda bem, porém foi necessário comentar o  @import _root por enquanto, mas sei que não é a opção que devo utilizar.  Uso o Visual Studio Code e seu terminal, assim tenho uma interface única e clean para trabalhar no Mac ou Windows.

Comment: @EduardoCorreia cara eu testei aqui e consegui. Na verdade da para fazer de várias formas tentei aqui e tudo deu certo, o único problema mesmo foi quando eu tentei trocar uma cor direto dentro do _variable.scss ai ele da pau mesmo. Mas se vc pegar alguma variável que está lá dentro e colocar dentro de um novacor.scss e importar antes do `/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables` ou do /bootstrap completo vai funcionar. Em último casso isso pode te ajudar muito!! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ovw43Dkp44

Comment: Olha só, este é o vídeo que usei como referencia mesmo! Eu não alterei cor alguma. só copiei e salvei como novo arquivo. Ja vi outras pessoas com a mesma situação. Ainda não resolvi, mas vou tentar refazer tudo para ter certeza que nada deu errado. Se souber de algo novo quanto a isso, agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @EduardoCorreia cara eu testei por conta própria e testei tb como o cara do vídeo e não tive problemas. Já que vai começar do 0, instale o Bootstrap e não mexa em NADA nele, ai vc cria um .CSS que vai ser o único .CSS que vc vai indexar na sua página, e no .SCSS desse .CSS vc faz assim http://prntscr.com/mxrh2x ou se preferir vc pode fazer assim: http://prntscr.com/mxrhq6 onde esse `minhacor` é um scss onde vc vai ter suas variáveis de cor alteradas que vc copiou do `_variables` original do Bootstrap. É basicamente isso, aqui funcionou das duas formas